# didUpdateLocations method not being called

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

My method didUpdateLocations never seems to be called? Why is this? I have added the keys to info.plist

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }



}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

    lat = locValue.latitude
    long = locValue.longitude

}
```

Comment: Does app ever show the allow location tracking prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `locationManager` a class variable. You're declaring it as a local variable in `viewDidLoad` which means it will be immediately deallocated because there are no strong references to it outside of this function.

```
class YourViewController : UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate 
{
    var locationManager : CLLocationManager?

    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager? = CLLocationManager()

        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
        {
            locationManager?.delegate = self
            locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of optional value: `var locationManager = CLLocationManager()`